# Syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR in

Tags: php

Что не так с этим OR?

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], '../uploads/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
$return['src'] = '/uploads/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

or

$return['link'] = YourImageLibrary::createThumbnail($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']);
```

Answer (score 2):

С ним не так только одно: его там не должно быть вообще!!!